# How to get properties and values using Jsoup for android

Tags: android, html, css

How can i get the properties and values from the following html codes using jsoup with android:

```
<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#d8a8d8'>&nbsp;</div> Actual Text <br>Text Inside br<br>
<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#dda0dd'>&nbsp;</div> This text Too.
```

**what i need is :**

**1. the background value of both div tags** - (i.e.- "*d8a8d8*" and  "*dda0dd*")

**2. texts after div**- (i.e.- "*Actual Text*" and "*This text Too.*")

**3. Texts after the br tag, which are just after first div** (i.e.- "*Text Inside br*")

So , how do i do it?

---

What i tried is:

```
  String st = "<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#d8a8d8'>&nbsp;</div> Actual Text <br>Text Inside br<br>
<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#dda0dd'>&nbsp;</div>";

 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
 ements divs = doc.select("div");

 for(Element elem : divs)
{
   System.out.println(elem.html()); //get all elements inside div

   String ss =  elem.attr("style");
   Log.d("logjsoup", "\n after Jsoup: " +  ss);
}
```

and i am getting all the values inside style of divs.

**How can i get the specific results i want?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#d8a8d8'>&nbsp;</div> Actual Text <br>Text Inside br<br> \n"+
                    "<div style='width:100px;height:100px;background:#dda0dd'>&nbsp;</div> This text Too.";
        //parse the html
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        //select the divs
        Elements divs = doc.select("div");
        // use a regex matcher to get the background values
        // pattern to look for all characters between "background:#" and "'"
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=background:#)(.*)(?=\")");
        for(Element e: divs){
            Matcher m = p.matcher(e.attributes().toString());
            while(m.find()){
                // background value 
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
            // text after the div which is the next sibling of the div 
            System.out.println(e.nextSibling().toString().trim());
            if(e.nextElementSibling()!= null){
                // text after first br tag; the nextElementsibling returns the br element next sibling of this br is the text after br
                System.out.println(e.nextElementSibling().nextSibling().toString());
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
        }
    } 
}
```